# How To Change Select to ng-invalid in Angular

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have an expiration month and year that appears in a form using a select input field.  When a user clicks the month and year ng-change fires a function checkDate() to validate.  I use the console to return if the date is valid or invalid.  I also show the error message stating the expiration date is invalid.  However, I am unable to give the select element an invalid state even if the form is not valid.  The class changes from ng-invalid to ng-valid on the select element even if the date is incorrect which ultimately makes my form valid.  How do I apply the invalid class to the select element if the select field is invalid?

HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="exp_year">Exp Year</label>
    <select id="exp_year" class="form-control" ng-model="exp_year" ng-change="checkDate()" required>
        <option value="" disabled><span class="pull-left">Year</span></option>
        <option value="{{ year }}" ng-repeat="year in years">{{ year }}</option>
    </select>
    <i class="material-icons pull-right select-icon">arrow_drop_down</i>
</div>

<small class="text-danger">{{errMessage}}</small>
```

JS

```
$scope.checkDate = function () {
    if (!($scope.exp_month && $scope.exp_month)) return;
    if ($scope.exp_month <= currentMonth && $scope.exp_year <= currentYear){
        console.log('this form is invalid')
        $scope.errMessage = 'Please enter a valid expiration date';
        return true
    } else {
        console.log('this form is valid')
        $scope.errMessage = '';
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of validating form inputs by adding `valid`/`invalid` classes, there is a better way of performing custom validation:

Using **`$scope.formName.inputName.$setValidity("reason", false)`** ([Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController))

So when you find your values are invalid (month-year combination expired in your case..), you can set validity to `false`. and when it is valid again, to `true`.

And you can use `$scope.formName.$valid` to know whether your form is valid or not. Based on that you can perform your further action.

[**Working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2vXh7hnsrVpBfXhZ8Okv?p=preview) made your example

Comment: Tanmay thanks! This worked perfectly. The ng-invalid-expired class is added and the form is invalid when the date is incorrect.

Comment: @NinaMorena glad I could help :)